# how to make a textview invisible

Tags: java, android, textview, android-studio

this is my first android app so plese bear with me, and also, if you suggest a answer, alternative method of completeing a task, please specify how and also in detail...

Here is my problem, after doing some research, and trying it out, my app FC when I have the following line (specified by *)

```
private TextView msg;

msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtviewOut) ;

*    msg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I have no idea why

here is the rest of all my code:

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textenter"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbledt1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Name"
        android:id="@+id/lbledt1"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter your date of birth (e.g. xx July 19xx)"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textenter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press this button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="You have been awesome since"
        android:id="@+id/txtviewOut"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtoutName"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtviewOut"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtOutDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtviewOut"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is from MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.helloandroidstudio;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button btnClick;
    private EditText Name, Date;
    private TextView msg, NameOut, DateOut;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button) ;
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textenter) ;
        Date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText) ;
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtviewOut) ;
        msg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        NameOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtoutName) ;
        DateOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutDate) ;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == btnClick)
        {
            if (Name.equals("") == false && Date.equals("") == false)
            {
                NameOut = Name;
                DateOut = Date;
                msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                msg.setText("Please complete both fields");
                msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        return;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: where is your textView with id txtviewOut in layout??

Comment: @Manishika he has. check into xml...

Comment: Add the fatal exception logs..

Comment: In your layout you have already set the visibility to invisible.

Comment: @AndroidWarrior yes that is a side route to not being able to set the visiblity, so I will just add the text "to make it visible"

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar and I run it in my phone, so I do not know where to get the fatal exception logs

Comment: It won't be visible if you even put text. If you put it in your layout textview will be invisible you can later on make it visible but it will be invisible by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think it should work,i analysed your code and didn't found any reason to not work.so i only suggest that,try to use:

```
to make it invisible by changing its opacity
msg.setalpha(0.0f);

and to make it visible by changing its opacity
msg.setalpha(1.0f);
```

Answer (score 17):

try to set in xml

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

and in your activity where you want it to be visible

```
object of texview.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 5):

`android:visibility="gone"` is better than just `invisible`, because
while it is invisible HINT-text is shown anyway. When it is "gone" Android moves other elements to the "gone" element place and all view is more beautiful. Of course depends on case.